# Problem when call asp.net file from vb.net with adodb.recordset with get method

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I build some project with client server architecture. On the server side, I have a VB.net server project, an ASP.net files and an Access database. On the client side, I have a VB.net client project.

The ASP.net file must return me an XML document. When I call ASP.net files with get method from my client side project with adodb.recordset object, the program throws an error with the following message:

```
'The connection cannot be used to perform this operation. It is either closed or invalid in this context.'.
```

But when I use this file without any get parameter or I run it from Visual Studio it works correctly.

Comment: Please edit the question to include the code which throws the exception.

Comment: How do you handle database connection?  It's like one call close the connection for future calls, or something like that.  Or may be you have many thread at a time, and a thread close the connection for all threads.